# grep of top output yields funny characters upon redirection to file

Tags: grep, top

I am running CentOS 6 and I am trying to grep the output of top and redirect it to a file.

I.e.

```
top -u user1 -n 1 | /bin/grep somecommand &> scratch.txt
```

The output of `vim scratch.txt` is

```
^[(B^[[m21329 user1    20   0 2855m 816m 757m S 607.2  1.3  86:36.36 somecommand                                                     ^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m
```

The output of `cat scratch.txt` is

```
21329 user1    20   0 2855m 816m 757m S 607.2  1.3  86:36.36 somecommand
```

QUESTION : Why do I see funny characters in vim and how do I get rid of them?

Comment: add -b for batch mode

Comment: That is a winner, add as answer please.

Comment: Browsing this at work. Enjoy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`top`s default output is intended for terminal. As such is uses various control codes (invisible when viewed in a terminal). Those include various ways to move around the screen. Style output etc.

To get a more friendly output for text files / editing or what ever use the batch mode.

```
top -b ...
```